# Make Image taller than background color

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, css

I want to make a banner which has an image with transparent background on the right and some text and button on the left side.

I have made a two column layout one containing the text and other containing the image displayed horizontally on large screen and stacked reversely on smaller screen.next I want to add some background color to both the columns so that they look like one entity. However I want the image to overflow the background color on top so that it

[looks some thing like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b3Uaj.png)

[But My current design looks like this:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QdjLX.jpg)

Here is my code:

```css
.row {
    background-color: #fff;
    padding-top: 20px;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
}

.textstyle h1 {
    font-size: 25px;
    font-weight: 700;
    color: #484848;
    line-height: 30px;
}

.textstyle p {
    font-size: 18px;
    font-weight: 200;
    color: #484848;
}

.imgbox {
    width: 100%;
    height: 400px;
}

.captionbox {
    padding-top: 80px;
    padding-left: 20px;
    padding-right: 20px;
}

.backcolor {
    background-color: #ccc;
    width: 100%;
    height: 400px;
}

.mybutton {
    cursor: pointer;
    background: #00A699 !important;
    color: #fff;
    border-radius: 20px;
    width: 200px;
    padding: 10px;
    font-size: 16px;
}

@media (max-width: 1000px) {
    .captionbox {
        padding-top: 10px;
    }
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="container">

<div class="row">

    <div class="backcolor">
        <div class="col-md-7 col-md-push-5">
            <div class=""><img src="http://i.imgur.com/GguXEnF.png" class="imgbox"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-5 col-md-pull-7">
            <div class="textstyle captionbox">
                <h1>Hosting Opens Up a world of opportunity</h1>
                <p>Earn Money Sharing Your Extra Space with Travellers.</p>
                <a href="https://google.com" target="_blank" class="btn btn-default mybutton">See What You Can Earn</a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
```

I tried using padding and margin on top but did not work, please suggest a solution.

Comment: You could set the height of the image to more than the container and use `overflow:visible`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Use position to make it upper and increase image height.**

```
.imgbox{
   width: 100%;
   height: 430px;
   position: absolute;
   top: -30px;
 }
```

```css
.row{
   background-color: #fff;
   padding-top: 20px;
   padding-bottom: 10px;
}
.textstyle h1{
   font-size: 25px;
   font-weight: 700;
   color:#484848;
   line-height: 30px;
}
.textstyle p{
   font-size:18px;
   font-weight:200;
   color:#484848;
}
.imgbox{
width: 100%;
height: 430px;
position: absolute;
top: -30px;
}
.captionbox{
padding-top: 80px;
padding-left: 20px;
padding-right: 20px;
}
.backcolor{
background-color: #ccc;
width: 100%;
height: 400px;
}
.mybutton{
cursor: pointer;
background: #00A699 !important;
color: #fff;
border-radius: 20px;
width:200px;
padding:10px;
font-size: 16px;
}
@media (max-width: 1000px){
.captionbox{
    padding-top: 10px;
 }
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="container">

            <div class="row">
                
                <div class="backcolor">
                <div class="col-md-7 col-xs-7 col-md-push-5 col-xs-push-5"><div class=""><img src="http://i.imgur.com/GguXEnF.png" class="imgbox"></div></div>
                <div class="col-md-5 col-xs-5 col-md-pull-7 col-xs-pull-7">
                    <div class="textstyle captionbox">
                    <h1>Hosting Opens Up a world of opportunity</h1>
                        <p>Earn Money Sharing Your Extra Space with Travellers.</p>
                        <a href="https://google.com" target="_blank" class="btn btn-default mybutton">See What You Can Earn</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Comment: Hi thank you for the solution it worked but I used position:relative as position:absolute was not behaving exactly.